# Raspberry Pi Zero W can't connect to ssh

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi-zero

I already tried everything what I found on the internet about this problem but nothing worked. I try to connect to my raspberry pi 0 w on ssh via cable but I only get "connection refused" error. I don't have micro USB keyboard and mouse so I can't do it like that. I think the problem could be that when I check the second network at "network and sharing" it says it doesn't have internet access. Any more advice what could I do?

I see my Pi as a network, I can ping it too but ssh never works. I made the ssh file without extension, wrote into the config file and cmdline file the necessary texts for them, tried pi@raspberrypi.local and with IP address too but nothing worked for me.

Comment: _I try to connect to my raspberry pi 0 w on ssh via cable_ - What do you mean "via cable", as far as I know the Pi Zero W has no LAN cable adapter: it's wif only, right?

Comment: I meant micro USB cable. The second port should be the data port for these

Comment: First you would need to enable SSH in raspi-config. Have you plugged it into OTG enabled port? Did you follow a guide like: https://artivis.github.io/post/2020/pi-zero/